# How to prevent users from entering invalid characters inside an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a text input field. How can I prevent users from entering spaces, and other other than  letters numbers or dashes (-).

Alphanumerics only - "The alphanumeric character set consists of the numbers 0 to 9 and letters A to Z. In the perl programming language, the underscore character ( _ ) is also considered to be a member of the alphanumeric set of characters"

This is for a field where users can pick a custom url. I would like to prevent users from entering invalid characters.

Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Make sure that whatever you do in Javascript, you also have some filtering once it reaches the server!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the jQuery [`keyup(..)`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) method. You will want to check that the `event.keyCode` is something valid. If it is not valid, you can prevent the event with [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Remember to validate the data sent to the server because anything you do in javascript can be subverted.

Here is a library to do it for you: http://www.itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/

Comment: Just curious . why not keypress ? or should we act safe and listen to keyup.keydown and keypress .

Comment: @KiranRuthR `keypress` is similar to `keydown` except that it only triggers once when a key is held down. i'm sure you could implement a solution using `keydown`. Read the jQuery docs for more information: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: The user can still paste text that includes forbidden characters.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO - JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ssuryar/z6h8jL3a/77/)

Sorry for the late response. Though my answer is late. I have modified few changes to the answer and here it goes.

**Validation Required**

1. Restrict Digits entering on initial
2. Restrict Spaces, special characters but allow backspace and delete
3. Enable Alpha Numeric Characters

   ```
     <input name="pac_code" id="input_8_6" type="text" value="" class="form-control medium pacerror pacvalid" data-rule-maxlength="9" data-rule-minlength="9" maxlength="9" minlength="9" placeholder="Porting authorisation code (PAC) *" data-rule-required="true"
       autocomplete="off" size="9">
     <label for="input_8_6" style="color: #ff0000;font-weight: 300;font-size: 12px;margin-bottom: 1%;">Example: ABC123456</label><br />
     <label class="PAC_error error" style="display:none;">Invalid PAC Format</label>
   </div>
   ```

JQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input_8_6').bind('keypress', function(event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\b]+$");
    var regchar = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z\b]+$");
    var regnum = new RegExp("^[0-9\b]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    var pacvalue = $(this).val().length;
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    } else if (pacvalue <= 2) {
      for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        if (!regchar.test(key)) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
      }
    } else if (pacvalue >= 3) {
      for (j = 4; j <= 9; j++) {
        if (!regnum.test(key)) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of Javascript validation libraries out there. A quick Google search for 'javascript validation' produced the [JQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin as the first hit, so that's probably a good place to start.

As @Chris Cooper said, make sure that you also do server-side validation, because it's pretty trivial for a user to turn off javascript and avoid your client-side validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

Though my answer is very late, but this may help for further readers/techie's.
Who wants to implement a textbox to accepts with below condition.

- should accept Alphabets.
- should accept Numbers.
- should not accept any special characters.

Below is the code.

```js
$("input[name='txtExample'] ").focus(function (e) {
  if (!(e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && ((e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57)  || (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) || (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) ))) {
   event.preventDefault();
  }
 }).keyup(function (e) {
  if (!(e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && ((e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57)  || (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) || (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) ))) {
  event.preventDefault();
   }
 }).keypress(function (e) {
  if (!(e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && ((e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57)  || (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) || (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) ))) {
   event.preventDefault();
  }
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="txtExample"/>
```

added with example.