# Allowing only Alphanumeric values

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent users from entering invalid characters inside an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543059/how-to-prevent-users-from-entering-invalid-characters-inside-an-input-field)

I have 3 textboxes on a page. One of them should allows numbers, the other alphabets and the 3rd either numbers or alphabets.

Since this is the only requirement, I do not want to use the validation plugin, or any other 3rd party plugin. How can I do this by creating my own plugin using pure jQuery?

This is what I have done but I get a feeling that the code will become too long

```
 $(this).keydown(function(e)
        {
            var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;            
            return (
                key == 8 || 
                key == 9 ||
                key == 46 ||
                (key >= 37 && key <= 40) ||
                (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
                (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cvus8/

Can anyone tell me which si the best way to approach this issue?

Comment: Regex can be an option for minimizing code size, but you'll have to dig in more.

Comment: Don't forget that users can also paste in text from the clipboard, as well as locale differences in character sets.

Comment: then how do I handle clipboard scenarios?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The better solution might be to go with regular expression based checks.  Example below will limit only alphanumeric characters in the field with id `text`:

```
$('#text').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work for symbols such as !@#$%^&*()

Comment: @CountMurphy The regular expression in the answer is designed to only allow upper/lower case letters and numbers.  It is not permitting symbols by design.  If you need symbols, you can expand the regular expression to include these.

Comment: Looks like I made a mistake in my test code.  The symbols mentioned above were showing up in my text box.  My mistake, your solution works.

Comment: @Kami This will still allow `^` and `´` as input. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Kallewallex That is unexpected. The regular expression is designed to only permit one or more lower case, and uppercase letters or numbers. It does not permit any symbols.  Can you double check your code, or create a new question with the code so that we can have a look.

Comment: @Kami With Safari 7.0 it will still allow `^` and `´` : http://jsfiddle.net/vwS9n/ However on mobile safari it won't.

Comment: it code do not allow the delete stick

Comment: @Hector The anwser above was in response to the question posed. Regex is not suitable for allowing special characters, you will need to use key checks like the OP to allow whichever special keys you need.

Comment: it allows !@#$%^&*() , because your implementation of regex see's the input as 1234567890 not taking in account that the event had a shift keypress too...

Comment: @LokizFenrir `String.fromCharCode()` is being used to convert to the correct value, as the charcode is different for `1` and `!`.  The code sample works as expected in latest versions of IE, Chrome, and Firefox.  But the code may need to be modified to suit specific cases.

Comment: @Kami Tested this a while ago, but remembered that i was stil able to enter !@#$%^&*(), when I checked it was because they are seen as a combination of 1234567890 and the shift key charcode. I have no Idea why this happened, but it ignored the fact that shift was held down and happily accepted the special characters in Opera, Safari, Firefox,Chrome an IE. Will test it again when I have free time.

Comment: Doesn't remove punctuation.

Answer (score 13):

A digit in the range 1-9 followed by zero or more other digits:

```
^[1-9]\d*$
```

Ensure that a string only contains (ASCII) alphanumeric characters, underscores and spaces

```
^[\w ]+$
```

Only Alphabets no space or _

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

To match a string that contains only those characters (or an empty string), try

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$
```

Some patterns that may help ..but I think you will have to modify them as per your need..I hope it help ..