# How to restrict alphabets and special characters in a text box using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Can someone please show me how to restrict alphabets and special characters excluding '-' into a text box using jquery?

Comment: [please show what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @marathonman good article!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That has been answered here:
[Allowing only Alphanumeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236651/allowing-only-alphanumeric-values)

You will just need to change the regex to allow for the -

```
$('#text').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

(That works, though someone more knowledgeable at regex may wish to confirm if that is the best way of adding the - to it)

http://jsfiddle.net/HGJb3/

edit: having re-read your question, if you mean you just want to allow numbers and a dash, it is http://jsfiddle.net/HGJb3/1/

either way - ("^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$") - that is the bit you need to play with to specify what is allowed.

Comment: I tried this code too which worked.

Comment: function allowOnlyNumber(eventInstance) {
            eventInstance = eventInstance || window.event;
            key = eventInstance.keyCode || eventInstance.which;
            if ((47 < key) && (key < 58) || key == 8 || key == 189 || key == 109) {
                return true;
            } else {
                if (eventInstance.preventDefault)
                    eventInstance.preventDefault();
                eventInstance.returnValue = false;
                return false;
            }
        }

Comment: Unfortunately, all examples I've found for doing this have the same problem: they don't prevent pasting code that contains forbidden characters.