# Disallowing unwanted characters in text input field with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, replace, textinput

I'm using this code which prevents the user from entering any whitespace in a username field on a registration page.

```
$(function(){
   $('#username').bind('input', function(){
   $(this).val(function(_, v){
       return v.replace(/\s+/g, '');
       });
    });
});
```

But is there a way to disallow all characters other than numeric, uppercase and lowercase?

So the only characters the user can enter would be :

```
0123456789 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
return v.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\d]/g, '');
```

Comment: Yep this one works and still allows the backspace to work, Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#username').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237018/1017882

EDIT (to allow backspace):

```
$('#username').keypress(function (e) {
    if (keyCode == 8 || (keyCode >= 35 && keyCode <= 40)) {
       return;
    }

    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

New `if` condition checks if the key pressed is an arrow, backspace or delete. If so, no point in progressing with the validation part of the code.

Comment: Ahhh not quite perfect, this prevents the backspace from working. Is there a fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
v.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 :]/g, "")
```

should do the trick